# django modelsTypeError: decoding str is not supported

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm a beginner trying to view a basic queryset with two records. I'm not able to process the request. Looking for some help.

```
class TestVenue(models.Model):
    venue_name      = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    venue_city      = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    venue_province  = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    venue_shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    my_date_field   = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.venue_name
```

my views.py is pretty simple

```
def venues_listview(request):
    template_name = 'venues_list.html'
    queryset = TestVenue.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset
        }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

from the shell i want to see my queryset but i get the following error:

```
>>> from venues.models import TestVenue
>>> TestVenue.object.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'TestVenue' has no attribute 'object'
>>> TestVenue.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\users\frank\desktop\test_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "C:\users\frank\desktop\test_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 589, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "C:\users\frank\desktop\test_env\src\venues\models.py", line 14, in __str__
    #         return self.venue_name
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line,

```
TestVenue.object.all()
```

It should be,

```
TestVenue.objects.all()
```

`objects` is the attribute which calls the default manager, not `object`.

Comment: Not Resolved
>>> TestVenue.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\users\frank\desktop\test_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 229, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "C:\users\frank\desktop\test_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 589, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "C:\users\frank\desktop\test_env\src\venues\models.py", line 14, in __str__
    #         return self.venue_name
TypeError: decoding str is not supported

Comment: I am using python 3.4

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: multiple times and made sure the files were saved ahead of time

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted my computer and it's now working. I had tried starting and stopping the server but that had not fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Accept your answer to be more clear that it is gone.